# Keeping a cell with the Specific Data at Last

Tags: sorting, ms-office, excel-2013, aspose-cells

I’m trying to Sort The Data. Which is working Perfectly fine .
And If I need some Specific Data to be on top I give it as

```
sorter.add(0,SortOrder.ASCENDING,"to be top Data");
```

in Aspose API Java.

But What Can I do For the Data to be always on the Bottom of the Sorting Range I have to Sort.
For Eg: I have a cell Value with Total as its data. I want this row to always come at the bottom
Attaching a Sample Screen Short and a File…

[image: Scrren Shot]

Comment: I do not think MS Excel allows you to sort this way, so, you got to devise some other way around or use custom approach manually. For example, you sort by Col1 and then by Col2. Then, you may replace the word “Total” in Col3 (you have to change your "Total" string accordingly) to something like “ZZTotal” or anything which suits the purpose. As letter Z is the last letter, therefore ZZTotal will always be at the bottom or last. You got to devise some approach to change your dynamic row/data accordingly first. Once, you have done data sorting, you may replace ZZTotal to "Total" again.

Comment: Well this I'll give a try